# Raspberry Pi (Sort of) Captive Portal

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq, access-point

I am trying to build a sort of captive portal out of a RPi3. I started by creating an [access point following these instructions.](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/) Next I  configured dnsmasq to point all traffic on wlan0 at itself. `echo 'address=/#/172.24.1.1' >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf`

Once connected all traffic is redirected back to my node app. Now here is where my problem begins. All traffic gets sent to my node app, including traffic that originates from the raspberry pi, so while on the box I  am unable to telnet to any websites, or install apps.

I believe the issue is with the iptable rules.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE  
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

I need all traffic that originates from the raspberry pi to be able to go out to the internet (through `eth0`)and all traffic that comes in through `wlan0` to continue to redirect to my node app.

**UPDATE:**

Here are the results of `ip route sh`

```
default via 10.1.10.1 dev eth0  metric 202 
10.1.10.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.10.87  metric 202 
172.24.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.24.1.1
```

As for what captive portal software I  am using the answer is none. I am using a Node JS app I  wrote. It is a simple Express JS app that redirects all paths to one page.

dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=wlan0                     # Use interface wlan0  
listen-address=172.24.1.1           # Explicitly specify the address to listen on  
bind-interfaces                     # Bind to the interface to make sure we aren't sending things elsewhere  
#server=8.8.8.8                     # Forward DNS requests to Google DNS  
domain-needed                       # Don't forward short names  
bogus-priv                          # Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces.  
dhcp-range=172.24.1.50,172.24.1.150,12h     # Assign IP addresses between 172.24.1.50 and 172.24.1.150 with a 12 hour lease time
address=/#/172.24.1.1
```

IP Tables

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Could you please paste more detail about your configuration? Like the routing rules "ip route sh", for the captive portal what are you using? coova-chilli?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by modifying the DNS? Now that you told everybody the wrong address, you'll never be able to forward traffic correctly. Give them the correct address, transparently snoop traffic. For HTTP: set up a transparent proxy[https://mitmproxy.org/doc/transparent/linux.html] (works with any proxy), and/or use something like [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/).

Comment: This project has been abandoned, but thanks all for the replies.